# Normal rings and being integrally closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. I am thinking about the condition of being integrally closed in relation to being normal. How do the following conditions relate to each other?

1. $A$ is normal
2. $A/\mathfrak p$ is integrally closed in $\text{Frac}(A / \mathfrak{p})$ for each prime $\mathfrak p$
3. $A_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{q}$ is a valuation ring for each prime $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A$ and each prime $\mathfrak{q}$ in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

I have found in my own thinking that (2) and (3) are equivalent, and that they imply (1), but I cannot get the other direction. Inn particular, is there an integrally closed domain $A$ such that $A/p$ is not integrally closed for some $p$?

Comment: While you say you've been "thinking about the condition of being integrally closed in relation to being normal," there's not much evidence of that in this post. Have you attempted to prove that any of these imply any of the other conditions, or looked for any counterexamples for any of the implications?

Comment: @KReiser fair point; thanks for your answer and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are tons of integrally closed domains $A$ with a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ so that $A/\mathfrak{p}$ isn't integrally closed. Take any non-normal affine variety, like $V(x^2-y^3)\subset \Bbb A^2_k$: $k[x,y]$ is a UFD, hence normal, but $k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)\cong k[t^2,t^3]$ which is not integrally closed in its field of fractions $k(t)$. So (1) does not imply (2).

Let me also point out that the condition in (3) of $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{q}$ being a valuation ring for all $\mathfrak{p,q}$ is incredibly uncommon: even when $A$ is the coordinate ring of a smooth variety over a field, the local ring of any point $\mathfrak{p}$ of codimension greater than one with $\mathfrak{q}=0$ provides a counterexample. Condition 3 should be equivalent to $A$ being regular of dimension one.